# core-plot : Scalling only x-axis by User Interaction

Tags: ios, core-plot

Working Core-Plot on iOS. I am setting `plotSpace.allowsUserInteraction = YES`.

I want to do scaling only X-axis by pinch.

For Example, max-range of Y-axis always view 100. max-range of X-axis view 60 to 120.

I think best solution that only X-axis scaling by horizon-pinch, Y-axis scalling by vertical-pinch.

Comment: The question is not clear. Can you please update it with more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a plot space delegate. Implement the `-plotSpace:willChangePlotRangeTo:forCoordinate:` delegate method and always return the original `yRange` for the `CPTCoordinateY`.

Answer (score 2):

```
[[self.graph defaultPlotSpace] setAllowsUserInteraction:YES];
[self.graph defaultPlotSpace].delegate = self;
```

than in delegate you want smth. like this

```
- (CPTPlotRange *)plotSpace:(CPTPlotSpace *)space willChangePlotRangeTo:(CPTPlotRange *)newRange forCoordinate:(CPTCoordinate)coordinate {

    if (CPTCoordinateY == coordinate) {
        CGRect chartBounds = self.graph.bounds;
        return [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(chartBounds.origin.y) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(chartBounds.size.height)];
    }

    return newRange;
}
```